# Bash loop, two conditions, first must be true and part of the loop

Tags: bash, if-statement, while-loop

I'm migrating a bunch of openvz containers and can only do one at a time for reasons.  This is very time consuming and if I'm not watching the destination node constantly I won't know if the migrations fail or are done.

So I'm trying to write a little shell script to do two things.  First, make sure the container ID that is being migrated shows up in the list of containers.  If it does not, exit the script and send me an email.  Second, as long as the first condition is true, watch for the status of the container to change to running and once that is true send me an email.

I have the second part of this working using until, I'm not sure that is the best way to go about it though and I need the first part, making sure the container exists to work as well.  Obviously both these tests need to run every loop in case the migration fails.  I just can't wrap my head around how to do this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Container ID: " -e CID
until vzlist -a | grep $CID | grep running
do
        sleep 600
done
echo "Migration of container $CID complete" | mail -s "Migration complete" red@cted.com
```

Comment: I'd use two separate loops; first, an `until vzlist -a | grep $CID` loop to wait for it to show up in the list (and some sort of timeout trigger to send an "it failed" email and exit the script). Then after that, a second loop to wait for "running" status.

Comment: The only problem with a timeout is that some containers take 20 minutes to migrate while others can take several hours. It all depends on the amount of data to move. So if I allow several hours for the bigger containers it could have failed long before I get the email.

Comment: Is there any way (that can be scripted) to tell whether a migration has failed, or just not succeeded yet? If not, fully scripting this is going to be basically impossible. What you might be able to do is have it notify you if a migration seems to be taking an unusually long time, requiring you to manually investigate whether it's failed or just slow, and reset the watcher script if it's just slow.

Comment: Once the migration starts the container ID shows up when you run vzlist -a.  That would be the time I kick off the script.  When a migration fails, the container is removed from the list when running vzlist -a.  So I can run vzlist -a | grep $CID and as long as that returns true the script can continue running and check for the migration to be complete.  If vzlist -a | grep $CID returns false, it should kick off an email to me and exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding how to interpret `vxlist -a` correctly, something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

emailTarget="red@cted.com"

read -p "Container ID: " -e CID

while true; do    # This loops until something `break`s it out of the loop

    # Capture the container status, so we can run multiple checks with
    # only one run of `vzlist`.
    containerStatus=$(vzlist -a | grep "$CID")


    if [[ -z "$containerStatus" ]]; then
        # If the the result was the empty string, our container is not
        # in the list, so apparently it's failed.
        echo "Migration of container $CID failed" | mail -s "Migration failed" "$emailTarget"
        break

    elif [[ "$containerStatus" = *"running"* ]]; then
        # It's in the list *and* has "running" status -- migration succeeded!
        echo "Migration of container $CID complete" | mail -s "Migration complete" "$emailTarget"
        break
    fi

    # If neither of those conditions was met, it's still trying;
    # wait 10 minutes and check again.
    sleep 600
done
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed and works perfectly.  Thank you!